# Does beaglebone black support gpu hardware acceleration?

Tags: video, sdl-2, beagleboneblack, hardware-acceleration

thanks in advance.
I'm trying to play video on beaglebone black (BBB) made by Texas Instrument.
Since there are a lot of good tutorials about using ffmpeg and SDL, I've decided to use it.
Get information about video and codec, decode frames using ffmpeg.
Display decoded frames to monitor using SDL.

I'm using SDL2 which uses renderer, texture to display image to screen.
According to SDL wiki, renderer uses GPU acceleration. 
But here's a problem. video is played too slow... about 0.5fps?

So I turned to SDL1.2 which uses software rendering. 
It displays yuv overlay through CPU RAM.

I thought that maybe BBB doesn't support GPU acceleration and googled about it but couldn't get answer. Any help please?
 Here's my code using SDL2.

```
 #include <libavutil/frame.h>
 #include <libavutil/avutil.h>
 #include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
 #include <libavformat/avformat.h>
 #include <libswscale/swscale.h>

 #include <SDL2/SDL.h>
 #include <SDL2/SDL_thread.h>

 #ifdef __MINGW32__
 #undef main /* Prevents SDL from overriding main() */
 #endif

#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/fb.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

AVFormatContext *pFormatCtx = NULL;
int             i, videoStream;
AVCodecContext  *pCodecCtx = NULL;
AVCodec         *pCodec = NULL;
AVFrame         *pFrame = NULL;
AVPacket        packet;
int             frameFinished;

SDL_Window    *window=NULL;
SDL_Renderer    *renderer=NULL;
SDL_Texture     *bmp=NULL;
SDL_Event       event;

int fbfd, ret;
struct fb_var_screeninfo fbvar;

if(argc < 2) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Usage: test <file>\n");
  exit(1);
}
// Register all formats and codecs
av_register_all();

if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO)) {
fprintf(stderr, "Could not initialize SDL - %s\n", SDL_GetError());
exit(1);
}

// Open video file
if(avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, argv[1], NULL, NULL)!=0)
return -1; // Couldn't open file

// Retrieve stream information
if(avformat_find_stream_info(pFormatCtx, NULL)<0)
return -1; // Couldn't find stream information

// Dump information about file onto standard error
av_dump_format(pFormatCtx, 0, argv[1], 0);

// Find the first video stream
videoStream=-1;
for(i=0; i<pFormatCtx->nb_streams; i++)
  if(pFormatCtx->streams[i]->codec->codec_type==AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
  videoStream=i;
  break;
}
if(videoStream==-1)
return -1; // Didn't find a video stream

// Get a pointer to the codec context for the video stream
pCodecCtx=pFormatCtx->streams[videoStream]->codec;
// Find the decoder for the video stream
pCodec=avcodec_find_decoder(pCodecCtx->codec_id);
if(pCodec==NULL) {
fprintf(stderr, "Unsupported codec!\n");
return -1; // Codec not found
}


// Open codec
if( avcodec_open2(pCodecCtx, pCodec, NULL)<0 )
return -1; // Could not open codec

// Allocate video frame
pFrame=av_frame_alloc();


int ctxW= pCodecCtx->width;
int ctxH= pCodecCtx->height;

 window =
  SDL_CreateWindow("test",
    SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 0, 0,
    SDL_WINDOW_BORDERLESS  SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN_DESKTOP);

 renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);

 // Allocate a place to put our YUV image on that screen
 bmp = SDL_CreateTexture(renderer, 
        SDL_PIXELFORMAT_YV12, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING, 
        pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height);

 av_init_packet(&packet);

 // Read frames and save first five frames to disk
 while(av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, &packet)>=0) {
  // Is this a packet from the video stream?
   if(packet.stream_index==videoStream) {
  // Decode video frame
    avcodec_decode_video2(pCodecCtx, pFrame, &frameFinished, &packet);

  // Did we get a video frame?
     if(frameFinished) {
       SDL_UpdateYUVTexture(bmp, NULL, pFrame->data[0], pFrame->linesize[0],
        pFrame->data[1], pFrame->linesize[1],
        pFrame->data[2], pFrame->linesize[2]);
      }

      SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
      SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, bmp, NULL, NULL);
      SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
   }
  SDL_Delay(15);


SDL_PollEvent(&event);
switch(event.type) {
case SDL_QUIT:
  SDL_Quit();
  exit(0);
  break;
default:
  break;
}


}

// Free the packet that was allocated by av_read_frame
 av_free_packet(&packet);

// Free the YUV frame
av_frame_free(&pFrame);

// Close the codec
avcodec_close(pCodecCtx);

// Close the video file
avformat_close_input(&pFormatCtx);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes beaglebone black does support gpu hardware acceleration,

from this wikipedia link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BeagleBoard

BBB has **PowerVR SGX530** GPU whose details can be found here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerVR#Series_5

This one from BBB official website http://beagleboard.org/BLACK

Processor: AM335x 1GHz ARM® Cortex-A8

512MB DDR3 RAM

4GB 8-bit eMMC on-board flash storage

**3D graphics accelerator**

NEON floating-point accelerator

2x PRU 32-bit microcontrollers

You can also check
REF: 
BBONEBLK_SRM BeagleBone Black System
Reference Manual
Rev A5.2

Comment: Do you know if any of the provided images have driver support for it so an openGL application could use it?